# Powerpoint VBA Loop not looping through all slides

Tags: vba, loops, powerpoint, shapes

Bit of an issue, I have some VBA code that loops through all of the sheets in my ppt, loops through all of the shapes in each ppt, and deletes the ppt if a specific string of text is not found. It seems to work perfectly other than the code seems to stop looping for no reason. I have to hit F5 about 4 times for the code to loop through all the sheets. It could be something to do with my code so I thought I'd try the good people of Stackoverflow first.

```
Public Sub ExportMBR()
Dim oSld As Slide
Dim oShp As Shape
Dim strSearch As String
Dim i As Integer

strSearch = "R&T MBR"
i = 0

For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    Debug.Print (ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)
    Debug.Print (oSld.Name)
    For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
        If oShp.HasTextFrame Then
            If oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Find(strSearch) Is Nothing Then
            Else
                Debug.Print (oSld.Name & " Slide found")
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next oShp
    If i = 0 Then
        Debug.Print (oSld.Name & " Deleting")
        oSld.Delete
        i = 0
    End If
    i = 0
Next oSld

myQ = "<afilepath>"
myName = myQ & "<anameformat>") & ".pptx"
ActivePresentation.SaveCopyAs myName

Call Shell("explorer.exe " & myQ, vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

There are 34 slides in my ppt, each run will loop through about 7 slides correctly identifying and deleting the slides I do not need, but then without any errors it will just stop looping and continue executing the rest of the code. The string is found on slides 17 and 18 if this makes a difference. I have added few bits extra to try and solve the problem like the debug.prints and the i = 0 but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Many thanks in advance!

ppw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you delete any object within a collection as you loop through each object in that collection, you need to count backwards. So in these cases you cannot use the For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides statement but do this instead:

```
Dim lCntr as Long
Dim oSld as Slide
For lCntr = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count to 1 Step -1
  Set oSld = ActivePresentation.Slides(lCntr)
  ' Do your stuff here...
  Set oSld = Nothing
Next
```

Download more free PowerPoint macros and add-ins at http://youpresent.co.uk

Comment: Thank you @JamieG for your explanation and fixed code.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Find(strSearch)` & `oSld.Delete` are at the same loop, you need to separate them !! 
 Address the slides which you want to del first and then del them.

For example: suppose that you have slide_1 & slide_2 & slide_3 and you want to del slide_1 & slide_2 & slide_3. Actually, your VBA only del slide_1 & slide_3.

In the loop `For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides`, the finding sequence should be slide_1 => slide_2 => slide_3. However, the first loop cycle will del slide_1, the remaining slides count become 2 (slide_2 & slide_3), so second loop cycle will start from slide_3. That's the reason why.

Comment: Bah, how stupid am I, I completely missed that one, thanks for the detailed reply!